# How to remove deleted files from File History on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I've removed some large files from my C drive, and now I want them gone from File History, too. It would seem that File History Cleanup would do this, based on what this dialog says:

[image: File History Cleanup dialog]

I'm not sure what "versions that were excluded or removed from your libraries" means, as I understand libraries to contain folders, not versions, but it sounds like in addition to past versions older than one year being deleted, files in the history that no longer exist will be deleted too. Anyway, that's my hope.

But, it doesn't happen. Files deleted from folders on the C drive continue to exist in the File History.

Anyone know how to clean out deleted files from File History? I could just go into the File History and delete them manually, but this seems like an unclean idea.